# TextPos not behaving with Booklet and Twoup

Tags: printing, textpos, booklet

I am using a combination of `booklet`, `twoup`, and `textpos` to create a printable booklet, and having a strange problem with the location of textblocks in print mode.  I've used this combination before to make documents that can be printed on a home printer, and it was beautiful.

When `booklet` is compiled in `noprint` mode, everything works perfectly, and it produces the correct output on half-letter size paper (or switch to a5, if you prefer).

However, when compiled in `print` mode, the textblocks are delayed until the  back page (the back cover).

Changing the order of loading packages did not produce any positive results.

I have the following MNWE, which is pared-down from a template I made and used for making booklets.  I have updated my TeX distribution recently, which may be the source of the problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[noprint,1to1]{booklet}          % run once, to set text on half-page
%\usepackage[print,1to1]{booklet}\nofiles   % final run, create the printable document  
\usepackage{twoup}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}  % allows for absolute placement of text

% this will set a half-letter size paper sheet, for making a `zine 
\setlength{\paperwidth}{5.5in}          % width = 11/2 = 5.5in
\setlength{\paperheight}{8.5in}         % height = 8.5in, width of letter paper

%% This command is necessary when using the booklet package
\AtBeginDocument{\setpdftargetpages}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% FRONT PAGE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \TPGrid{16}{16}
    \begin{textblock}{16}(0,2)
        \centering
        \noindent \fbox{\huge FRONT PAGE}
    \end{textblock}
    \begin{textblock}{16}[0.5,0.5](8,8)
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (12,14);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{textblock}
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\mbox{}
\null\ ~ % use all of them for good measure
\clearpage
\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% FIRST SPREAD
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{arabic} %this restarts page numbering with standard numbers

% page 1
\section{FIRST PAGE}
\TPGrid{16}{16}
\begin{textblock}{10}[0.5,0.5](8,6)
    \fbox{\textcolor{blue}{THIS CONTENT BELONGS ON FIRST PAGE}}
\end{textblock}
\subsection{some text}
\lipsum[6]
\mbox{}
\null\ ~ % use all of them for good measure
\clearpage
\newpage

% page 2
\section{SECOND PAGE}
\lipsum[1-2]
\mbox{}
\clearpage
\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% BACK COVER
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \TPGrid{16}{16}
    \begin{textblock}{16}[0.5,0.5](8,8)
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw(0,0) rectangle (12,14);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{textblock}
    \begin{textblock}{16}[0.5,0.5](8,14)
        \centering
        \fbox{\huge \textcolor{red}{BACK PAGE}}
    \end{textblock}
\end{titlepage}
\mbox{}
\null\ ~
\clearpage
\newpage

\end{document}
```

To reproduce the error, first compile with the `noprint` option to the booklet package.  Then comment out this line, uncomment the line below to compile with the `print` option.

On first compile, the textblocks will appear on correct pages.  On second compile, to make the booklet, the textblocks all appear on the back page (which appears on left-hand side of first full sheet).  Other elements appear as expected.

Except for the textblocks, everything else works fine.  This includes `\includegraphics` commands, internal tables, internal and external hyperrefs, and other layout choices.

I am compiling on a Mac, using TexShop v 4.70 and TexLive 2022. If the MNWE works for you, please tell me your version.

Any suggestions are appreciated.  I've been fiddling with this for hours, and found nothing in the documentation of either package.

Comment: The issue might be related to the shipout problem TextPos has with some other packages.  I have checked versions from a backup log, and in both I am using booklet v0.7b and twoup v1.3.  However I used to use TextPost v1.8, and am now on v1.10.  Dragging the older .sty file to the directory gave unexpected error `Output routine didn't use all of \box255`

Comment: I "resolved" my issue, which is to drag both TextPos v1.8 AND EveryShipout v3.00 into the directory.  However, it would be optimal to have a solution that works with TexLive 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make a smaller MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[noprint,1to1]{booklet}       % this works as expected
\usepackage[print,1to1]{booklet} % this doesn't
\AtBeginDocument{\setpdftargetpages}

% both of the following show the same behaviour
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
%\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\TPGrid{16}{16}

% We expect the text 'Page 1' and 'front page textblock' to appear on
% the first page, of four in the booklet.
%
% However the textblock in fact ends up on the last page of the 4-page
% signature.

\begin{document}
Page 1
\begin{textblock}{10}(8,8)
front page textblock
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

I think the problem here may be with the `booklet` package.

I notice that the `booklet` package redefines `\shipout`.  The important change between `textpos` 1.9 and 1.10 was that (after prompting from the CTAN maintainers) it changed to support the new LaTeX3 shipout hooks.  It looks like the `booklet` package hasn't yet done that (TeXLive 2022 seems to include ‘booklet 2009/09/02 v0.7b’, so predates the change), and that means that `textpos` 1.10 and `booklet` are just not going to be friends, and indeed `booklet` is likely to behave erratically with other packages which use the new shipout hooks.  It's worth noting that the `everyshi` package (which is the package that provides `\EveryShipout`) has declared itself obsolete, and now works only as a compatibility shim, implemented in terms of the new shipout hooks.

I can suggest an alternative strategy to the OP, however.

When I've wanted to produce booklet/signatures, I've used the `pdfpages` package.  To use this, I *remove* the booklet package from the above document, compile it to `try-mwe.pdf`, and create a separate document `try-booklet.tex` containing the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,landscape,booklet]{try-mwe.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I can then run pdflatex on `try-booklet.tex` to get a 4-page booklet.  That scales down the input document, so to get the intended effect I'd have to scale up all the sizes in the original document.  That means there are two steps involved in assembling the document, and some extra arithmetic, but it means that all of the PDF gymnastics are confined to a separate, isolated, step.

Comment: That does make sense.  Apparently `booklet` is still on beta v0.7b, last updated in 2009.